# Do C# Streams behave like pointers?

Tags: c#, pointers, stream

I've this class

```
class CacheHelper() {
    private Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> cacher;
    // ... other porps, f's...etc

    public MemoryStream GetImageStream(string fileName)
        {
            if (!cacher.ContainsKey(fileName))
                return null;
            MemoryStream memStream = null;
            cacher.TryGetValue(fileName, out memStream); // TODO
            return memStream;
        }

}
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
Stream fileStream = _cacheHelper.GetImageStream(filePath);
```

and When I'm done I'm closing `fileStream` like this:

```
if(fileStream!=null)
    fileStream.Dispose();
```

I'm not sure what's going on underneath `Stream` implementation in C#, so I'm afraid that I'm closing the original `MemoryStream` (the one inside the internal cacher Dictionary) if I'm closing `fileStream`, i.e. implemented on top of pointers, or something.

Comment: should be fairly easy to test. Add one, close it, try to write to it ...

Comment: Streams aren't really reusable like that. They have a `Position` which the caller can use to seek in the stream (assuming it supports that). Can you cache the image as some kind of image object or maybe just a `byte[]`?

Comment: [Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A `MemoryStream` is a class. All classes are `reference types` which means that the variable you have is indeed a kind of pointer to the actual instance. What happens is that you pass a **reference** of your memory stream somewhere. If you don't want to close that stream, you should not do so.

A better implementation might be to either cache byte arrays or handle everything using streams inside the cache itself. Passing a stateful object from your cache to somewhere it's used and expecting it to keep it's original state is not such a good design. It's very easy to make mistakes that way.